# DB2 lock timeout in connection string

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

DB2 has a database-wide property [locktimeout](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000329.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-2-6-7-56). Is it possible to override it in client connections? Something like this:

```
jdbc:db2://host:port/dbname:locktimeout=value;
```

One jdbc-based tool from IBM has the option `destdb_locktimeout`:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.workspaces.doc/refs/rssstageprop_dup.htm

I wonder how they implement it

**UPD**:

```
db2jcc.jar\com\ibm\db2\jcc\b\db.class contains the string "currentLockTimeout".
```

Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver property name is `currentLockTimeout`.

[Manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052522.html)